# Typedef application in c++

Tags: c++, casting, typedef

Is there a simple way to use a typedef based on an if condition?

example:

```
int depth = someObject->getDepth();

if(depth == 32){
    typedef float cast;
}
else{
     typedef double cast;
 }

 cast *data = (cast)someObject->getData();
```

thanks

Comment: Runtime typedefs aren't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refactor the implemantation in another function:

```
template<class T>
void foo(T* data){
  // ...
}

int depth = someObject->getDepth();
if(depth == 32)
  foo(static_cast<float*>(someObject->getData());
else
  foo(static_cast<double*>(someObject->getData());
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that because a `typedef` is a static, compile time construct. Indeed the entire type system in C++ is static. You could solve your problem with something like `boost::variant<float, double>`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are as close as you can get

```
template< class cast>
void do_task(cast* object) {

}

int main() {
    int depth = someObject->getDepth();
    if (depth == 32)
        do_task( static_cast<float*>(someObject->getData()));
    else 
        do_task( static_cast<double*>(someObject->getData()));
}
```

Comment: @Xeo: Since he was casting to `float` and `double`, I assumed it was something that could implicitly cast to those.  It was a silly assumption to make, and also I didn't notice that he sometimes uses `getData` as a pointer, and sometimes an object.  That.... confuses matters.

Comment: @Miek: `cast *data = (cast)someObject->getData();` You can't cast a `float` to a `float*`, no matter what `getData` returns.

Comment: @Miek: well now you're casting `getData` to a `float*`, and assigning it to a `float**`.  Still wrong.